# How to use enter key as while condition

Tags: c++, while-loop, enter

I want to write a program that a part of it is that input some numbers that there is some spaces between them for example :1 2 3 and with a while loop i input them 
i want to have pressing enter key as condition of my while loop but how?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i m using c++ language

Answer (score 2):

[stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) would be useful here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    string input;
    getline( cin, input );
    stringstream ss( input );
    while ( ss >> x )
    {
        // Do something with x
    }
}
```